# Why are there no type converters between collection types (e.g. arrays and lists)?

Tags: c#, collections, typeconverter

For my task, I cannot use casting because I don't know which type should an object be converted to at runtime. So I use `TypeConverter` to solve this problem.

There are converters between simple types such as `Int32` and `String` etc, but there doesn't seem to be any converters between collection types such as `T[]` and `List<T>`.

I see no problem in implementing them myself, but I was wondering if there was some design decision for not implementing them from day 0?

Comment: At the end of the day, all of those collections are just IEnumerables. Each of those types have their own constructors which accept an IEnumerable, and give you collection that you're after. I'm not sure what the benefit of TypeConverters would be, when ultimately you're just talking about an implementation detail (e.g. Array vs List)

Comment: `Linq` has lots of methods that will do the conversion between generic types for you, such as `ToList()` and `ToArray()`. Can you add some code to show us what problems you are having?

Comment: What's the point? It's very easy to create a `List` from an `Array` and vice versa, no need for a TypeConverter. It seems likely that this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

In C#, there is a CollectionConverter whose base class is TypeConverter.

More on it here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.collectionconverter?view=netframework-4.8

This class provides several methods like [CanConvertFrom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.canconvertfrom?view=netframework-4.8#System_ComponentModel_TypeConverter_CanConvertFrom_System_Type_), [CanConvertTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.canconvertto?view=netframework-4.8#System_ComponentModel_TypeConverter_CanConvertTo_System_Type_) etc.